# xamarin android xml files code helper

Tags: xml, xamarin.android

Is there a tool or option to make writing xml files is not a such disaster as it is now?

I'm looking for tool for xml layout files that will predict incoming code and let me chose it (like all platforms do).

(if i write "Linea" - it will give me something like LinearLayout and so on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/questions/enable-axml-intellisense/

For me works fine!